# modify cache expiration of existing full page cache hole punch

Tags: magento-enterprise, full-page-cache

I'd like to punch a hole in the full page cache for the top menu of a site.  While digging through some Enterprise code, I see that the top menu has an existing hole punched:

```
//  app/code/coe/Enterprise/PageCache/etc/cache.xml
<catalog_navigation>
    <block>page/html_topmenu</block>
    <name>catalog.topnav</name>
    <placeholder>TOPMENU</placeholder>
    <container>Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Catalognavigation</container>
    <cache_lifetime>86400</cache_lifetime>
</catalog_navigation>
```

However, I'd like to change the cache_lifetime to be much shorter (1 second).  What is the best way to modify the cache_lifetime without modifying core code?

Comment: Why on earth do you want a 1s cache expiry??

Comment: To effectively disable caching the top menu.  It's very... dynamic.

Comment: This is the wrong way to go about it, I believe. I think if you pass `<cache_lifetime />` you will get what you want. FWIW I can't imagine such dynamism to be good for the user or for search engines, but obviously I don't know your use case.

Comment: B2B site that's closed to the world.  SEO isn't a concern.  They dynamic aspects weren't my idea. =/

Answer (score 2):

I believe that if you declare a custom module as `<depends>` on `<Enterprise_PageCache/>` and create a *cache.xml* file which contains the following, you will effectively override the core `cache_lifetime` value:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cache>
    <catalog_navigation>
        <cache_lifetime>1</cache_lifetime>
    </catalog_navigation>
</cache>
```

Comment: Shouldn't catalog_navigation be wrapped in :<config><placeholders>?